# Get HTML source code from CefSharp web browser

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am using aCefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser (Version 47.0.3.0) to load a web page.  Some point after the page has loaded I want to get the source code.

I have called:

```
wb.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync()
```

however it does not appear to be returning all the source code (I believe this is because there are child frames).

If I call:

```
wb.GetBrowser().MainFrame.ViewSource()
```

I can see it lists all the source code (including the inner frames).

I would like to get the same result as ViewSource(). Could some one point me in the right direction please?

**Update – Added Code example**

*Note: The address the web browser is pointing too will only work up to and including 10/03/2016. After that it may display different data which is not what I would be looking at.*

In the frmSelection.xaml file

```
<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="wb" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
```

In the frmSelection.xaml.cs file

```
public partial class frmSelection : UserControl
{
    private System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer wbTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

    public frmSelection()
    {

         InitializeComponent();

         // This timer will start when a web page has been loaded.
         // It will wait 4 seconds and then call wbTimer_Tick which 
         // will then see if data can be extracted from the web page.
         wbTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4);
         wbTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(wbTimer_Tick);

         wb.Address = "http://www.racingpost.com/horses2/cards/card.sd?race_id=644222&r_date=2016-03-10#raceTabs=sc_";

         wb.FrameLoadEnd += new EventHandler<CefSharp.FrameLoadEndEventArgs>(wb_FrameLoadEnd);

    }

        void wb_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, CefSharp.FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
        {
            if (wbTimer.IsEnabled)
                wbTimer.Stop();

            wbTimer.Start();
        }

    void wbTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wbTimer.Stop();
        string html = GetHTMLFromWebBrowser();
    }

    private string GetHTMLFromWebBrowser()
    {
         // call the ViewSource method which will open up notepad and display the html.
         // this is just so I can compare it to the html returned in GetSourceAsync()
         // This is displaying all the html code (including child frames)
            wb.GetBrowser().MainFrame.ViewSource();

         // Get the html source code from the main Frame.
            // This is displaying only code in the main frame and not any child frames of it.
            Task<String> taskHtml = wb.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();

            string response = taskHtml.Result;
     return response;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you share some more code? I can't reproduce your problem, I get the same text with `GetSourceAsync` as with `ViewSource`. Tried it with `Address` set to `http://stackoverflow.com` (it has two frames, one `iframe` and the main frame)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I have added example source to the original post.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't think I quite get this `DispatcherTimer` solution. I would do it like this:

```
public frmSelection()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    wb.FrameLoadEnd += WebBrowserFrameLoadEnded;
    wb.Address = "http://www.racingpost.com/horses2/cards/card.sd?race_id=644222&r_date=2016-03-10#raceTabs=sc_";
}

private void WebBrowserFrameLoadEnded(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Frame.IsMain)
    {
        wb.ViewSource();
        wb.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
        {
            var html = taskHtml.Result;
        });
    }
}
```

I did a diff on the output of `ViewSource` and the text in the `html` variable and they are the same, so I can't reproduce your problem here.

This said, I noticed that the main frame gets loaded pretty late, so you have to wait quite a while until the notepad pops up with the source.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback on my code, I have sine updated it to reflect your example.

I have run the code on another computer since posting the example and I get the same results as you (both return the full source code).  I can only conclude there is something weird going on with my machine and I will consider doing a format.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue trying to get click on and item located in a frame and not on the main frame.  Using the example in your answer, I wrote the following extension method:

```
    public static IFrame GetFrame(this ChromiumWebBrowser browser, string FrameName)
    {
        IFrame frame = null;

        var identifiers = browser.GetBrowser().GetFrameIdentifiers();

        foreach (var i in identifiers)
        {
            frame = browser.GetBrowser().GetFrame(i);
            if (frame.Name == FrameName)
                return frame;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

If you have a "using" on your form for the module that contains this method you can do something like:

```
var frame = browser.GetFrame("nameofframe");
if (frame != null)
{
    string HTML = await frame.GetSourceAsync();
}
```

Of course you need to make sure the page load is complete before using this, but I plan to use it a lot.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<String> taskHtml = CW.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();
    textBox1.Text = taskHtml.Result;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply