# Get loaded page source in CefSharp webbrowser

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, cefsharp

I'm wanting to get source code of a web page based on Angular (so cannot use HttpClient or WebClient, page source completes after running JS), tried to use CefSharp (v.100) but cannot find a way to get page source.
I found `EvaluateScriptAsync` and `webBrowser.Document` but no one works in version 100.

[Update]
I need to get a resource link from source, or even if I can do it via RequestHandle to get a resource link which requested after Angular rendering.

Comment: Hi! Give an example of the code that you got. And maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890355/get-html-source-code-from-cefsharp-web-browser

Answer (score 0):

Use [GetSourceAsync](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/100.0.x/html/Overload_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_GetSourceAsync.htm) to get the source.

```cs
//add using CefSharp;
var source = await chromiumWebBrowser.GetSourceAsync();
```

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't show updated source (after running JS scripts).I want to get source code after running Angular.

Comment: You will need to provide a code example, edit your original question. Most common cause is you aren't waiting for the changes you've made to render.